# How to run jquery function after AJAX load

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, response

i have native AJAX function to load image. How i load Jquery function after native AJAX successfully load?

Here is my AJAX :

```
function loadImage() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("imageLoco").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementsByClassName("media-pv").style.height = document.getElementsByClassName("media-pv").clientWidth;
       } else {
            document.getElementById("imageLoco").innerHTML = "<img src='images/loader.gif' />";
       }
    }

    var url = "get_media.php";

    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And here is Jquery function ,that i want to load :

```
$('.media-pv').css({                    
   height : $('.media-pv').width()
});
```

I put my AJAX after `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` , and Jquery not change `.media-pv` class height. How to handle that?

Thank you..

Comment: why mix native javascript and jQuery... use `jQuery.ajax()`

Comment: try coding the jquery code after this line document.getElementsByClassName("media-pv")...
//jquery code here

Comment: It have same result, i already try using Jquery AJAX like this sample [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/fanjavaid/jMeEg/)

Comment: Why do you want to do that in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

try this code. not tested but should be work.

```
function loadImage() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("imageLoco").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            //document.getElementsByClassName("media-pv").style.height = document.getElementsByClassName("media-pv").clientWidth;
            //[updated code]
            changeHeight();
       } else {
            document.getElementById("imageLoco").innerHTML = "<img src='images/loader.gif' />";
       }
    }

    var url = "get_media.php";

    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function changeHeight(){

    if(domReady == true){
        $('.media-pv').css({                    
           height : $('.media-pv').width()
        });

        if(tempInterval){
            clearInterval(tempInterval);    
        }        

    }else{
        tempInterval = setInterval(changeHeight,100);    
    }


}

var domReady = false;
var tempInterval;
$(document).ready(function(){
    domReady = true;
});
```